# Create a profile page to display data based on a database value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to learn more about PDO, so please be patient and helpful, not rudely critical.

I have a database that holds quite a bit of information about different characters.  Each character has several different rows of information: id, name, breed, gender, sire, dam and so on and so forth.  Right now, it's all just being displayed on one page, like so:

1 - Frank - Horse - Blah Blah - Blah Blah
2 - Mary - Horse - Blah Blah - Blah Blah

What I'd like is for the PHP to create a link based on the ID and when clicked, it takes the user to a page that displays the information for the character with that ID.  So the link would be something like profile.php?id=1, and the first page would look much cleaner.

Does anyone know of any good tutorials showcasing this, or would anyone be willing to help a rookie out?  Please be detailed and specific if you'd like to help.  I can't seem to find a nice tutorial about this without having to build an entire register/login script, which really is unnecessary for what I need.

Here is my current code (which I understand is very basic; I'm still trying to switch from the old mysql to PDO, so I'm starting from scratch):

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Database</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <?php
    $host = '***';
    $dbName = '***';
     $username = '***';
     $password = '***';

     $dbCon = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$dbName, $username, $password); 

     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM characters ORDER BY name';
     $stmt = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->execute();
     while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
     {

         echo $row[1] . "<br/>";

     } 
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You are not going to find a tutorial explaining the exact issues you have. The tutorials explain in general how to do stuff, which you have to apply while implementing your own code. Instead of asking for a tutorial, ask specific questions around what you want to achieve.

Comment: There are tons of tutorials out there explaining how to write web pages. SO is a QA website, nobody is going to write you a tutorial here.

Comment: I'm trying to make you realise that you are looking for sg that does not exist and that you are jumping too far ahead by trying to create a database driven web page, when you lack the basic stuff.

Comment: What am I lacking, besides knowledge of PHP and PDO?  I'm not trying to create a database-drive web page.  This is one page on my website that is displaying data from a database, which is easier and more efficient than if I were to make one giant HTML page with a bunch of data.  You have no idea what my HTML skills are, so you really have no room to judge.  The above code is basic because it's a test page.  And what I'm asking seems pretty basic to me, which is why I'm asking, which is the point of this website.

Comment: This site is more for answers to specific problems. For example, if you'd said you were getting an error when you try to access $row[1], i would've said, [mysqli's fetch function/method](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) requires you to have used [bind_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) first. You might want to check out [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#107568) on php.net (shows an easier way to pull rows from a result set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM characters ORDER BY name';
     $stmt = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //allows you to refer to them by column name rather than by number
     $stmt->execute();
     while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
     {

         echo "<a href='profile.php?id=".$row['id'] . "'>".$row['name']."</a><br/>"; //builds the link

     }
```

Comment: So then on my profile.php page, how would I tell the page to pull the information for only the ID that was clicked on?

Comment: This is not a tutorial, this is a copy-paste solution with practically no explanation.

Comment: @Shadow: he didn't ask for a tutorial. He asked for a tutorial OR for help; I gave him help rather than a tutorial. @Lec: You would need to modify the query to use the `$_GET['id']` value provided so that you are only pulling up the one record. Then you would proceed the same way as above and echo the information.

Comment: @shadow I do not have a lack of HTML knowledge, but thank you for your criticism.

Comment: @RichardTheobald  So if my profile.php page is the same code as above, I would change this line: $sql = 'SELECT * FROM characters ORDER BY name'; to a $_GET statement?

Comment: `$sql = 'Select * from characters where id = :id';` After preparing but before executing: `$stmt->bindParam(':id',$_GET['id']);`

Comment: Thank you so very much!  Works like a charm!  Your help was much appreciated!  Cheers!

Comment: its working fine to fetch & display results, please tell me what code i need to use for `editing those information & save in database`.